# Regex not giving output as desired

Tags: java, regex

I am using the regex - **[{]{[}][}]** for the input **{{id}}** 
The output I expect is **id**. But I am getting **{{id}}**.

My java code is as below:

```
  String string = "\"{\n" +
                "    \"id\": {{dsm_id}},\n" +
                "    \"title\": \"Automation Test\",\n" +
                "    \"code\": \"aut_test\",\n" +
                "    \"companyId\": 286,\n" +
                "    \"enabled\": true,\n" +
                "    \"enableAdvanceFilter\": false,\n" +
                "    \"deleteAfterScheduledTime\": false,\n" +
                "    \"enableDataStoreLog\": false\n" +
                "}\"";
        String patternString = "[{][{](.*)[}][}]";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            allMatches.add(matcher.group());
        }
        System.out.println(allMatches);
```

The only solution I need is having the right regex. I cannot use or don't want to use DTO or Json parser here.

Comment: Is there any certain requirement to read value of id by regex only as there are simple and assured way to read "id" by  converting json string to Object and read a value?

Comment: Thats thr way I can use, But I would not like to go that way. As I dont need to do any other operation on json. And it will just increase the execution time. Moreover, in other scenarios the string gets much more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use patter group incorrectly. Try this one:

```
String patternString = "[{][{](?<id>.*)[}][}]";
// String patternString = "\\{\\{(?<id>[^}]+)}}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    allMatches.add(matcher.group("id"));
}
```

In case you do not want to use `name group`:

```
String patternString = "[{][{](.*)[}][}]";
//String patternString = "\\{\\{([^}]+)}}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    allMatches.add(matcher.group(1));
}
```

But I recommend you use another approach: using e.g. **Jackson** to convert this **JSON** to `Map<String, Object>` and retrieve required fields.

Comment: I cannot use ?<id>. It can be any string between {{ and }}.

Comment: This not a problem. this is just `name group`. You can get any string between `{{}}`

Comment: @ oleg.cherednik Thank you. It did solved my problem

Comment: It's not really JSON, it's more like a template string. I doubt any JSON library parsing library can parse this without spitting out an error.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to convert it to object and then you can find whatever you need.

Create DTO object

```
    public class DsmDto{
     private String id;
     private String title;
     private String code;
     private float companyId;
     private boolean enabled;
     private boolean enableAdvanceFilter;
     private boolean deleteAfterScheduledTime;
     private boolean enableDataStoreLog;


     // Getter Methods 

     public String getId() {
      return id;
     }

     public String getTitle() {
      return title;
     }

     public String getCode() {
      return code;
     }

     public float getCompanyId() {
      return companyId;
     }

     public boolean getEnabled() {
      return enabled;
     }

     public boolean getEnableAdvanceFilter() {
      return enableAdvanceFilter;
     }

     public boolean getDeleteAfterScheduledTime() {
      return deleteAfterScheduledTime;
     }

     public boolean getEnableDataStoreLog() {
      return enableDataStoreLog;
     }

     // Setter Methods 

     public void setId(String id) {
      this.id = id;
     }

     public void setTitle(String title) {
      this.title = title;
     }

     public void setCode(String code) {
      this.code = code;
     }

     public void setCompanyId(float companyId) {
      this.companyId = companyId;
     }

     public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
      this.enabled = enabled;
     }

     public void setEnableAdvanceFilter(boolean enableAdvanceFilter) {
      this.enableAdvanceFilter = enableAdvanceFilter;
     }

     public void setDeleteAfterScheduledTime(boolean deleteAfterScheduledTime) {
      this.deleteAfterScheduledTime = deleteAfterScheduledTime;
     }

     public void setEnableDataStoreLog(boolean enableDataStoreLog) {
      this.enableDataStoreLog = enableDataStoreLog;
     }
    }
```

Create converter class and convert method

```
public class DmsConverter{

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

public static DsmDto jsonToDsm(String json){
    return mapper.readValue(json, DsmDto.class);
}

}
```

Usage:

```
DsmDto dsmDto = DsmConverter.jsonToDsm(json);
System.out.println(dsmDto.getId());
```

Comment: I understand that it can be done this way. But I am passing data from excel and the json can be anything. Therefore, using DTO is not the approach I can go for here.